# Does Meilisearch have a limit for how many results it can give when searching?

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I have a model, let's call it `Entry`.

In a view, I have a paginated table (35 per page) with a search bar that lists every entry.

When the view loads, `meilisearch` is called to retrieve the first page of results. This is done with a `search` query using the search bar's value (it starts out empty). The initial query to the search endpoint is `q="", limit=35, offset=0`.

When I click on the pagination buttons, `meilisearch` is called again, using the page number for the offset. For example, for page 2 the query should be `q="", limit=35, offset=35`.

This works up until page 30. Then no results are shown, even though I have more than 100 pages worth of `entries` in my database.

---

I didn't know why this happened and assumed it was something weird going on with the `laravel/scout` or `meilisearch/meilisearch-php`. After some debugging, I found nothing and decided to run the query myself using cURL.

```bash
curl \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer my-meilisearch-key" \
    -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexes/my-index/search
    -d '{"q":"","limit":5,"offset":1000}'
```

The results are below.

[image: Meilisearch results]

Just to be clear, it I had used `offset: 999`, the search would have returned 1 hit. 1000 is a very peculiar number so I'm wondering if there's a configuration value somewhere that I could tweak to get as many results as I possibly can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## After asking around, I got the answer I needed on Discord by the user Rapand.

---

As I suspected, Meilisearch did have a default 1000 results per search limit. This is configured by the `maxTotalHits` pagination option. To quote from their [documentation](https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/api/settings.html#pagination) :

> `maxTotalHits` takes priority over search parameters such as `limit`, `offset`, `hitsPerPage`, and `page`.
>
> For example, if you set `maxTotalHits` to 100, you will not be able to access search results beyond 100 no matter the value configured for `offset`.

To update my pagination's limits, I just ran

```bash
curl \
    -X PATCH 'http://localhost:7700/indexes/my-index/settings/pagination' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer my-meilisearch-key' \
    -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
    -d '{"maxTotalHits": 20000}'
```